# Extracting Individual Elements From a JSON String

Tags: java, json, facebook

I know this could have been asked, but I couldn't get a specific answer. I have a json String:

```
GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphPlace, state={"id":"268367713308665","category":"School","location":{"state":"","zip":"","longitude":32.631482614136,"latitude":0.24519375867929,"country":"Uganda","city":"Kampala","street":"PO BOX 28493"},"category_list":[{"id":"365182493518892","name":"School"}],"name":"Little Wonders Montessori"}}
GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphPlace, state={"id":"142442605900768","category":"Education","location":{"state":"","zip":"","longitude":32.606752647018,"latitude":0.28746491511647,"country":"Uganda","city":"Kampala","street":"Heritage\/ Kiwafu Stage, Wheeling Zone, Gaba Road, Kansanga"},"category_list":[{"id":"151676848220295","name":"Education"}],"name":"Wisdomgate Pre-School, Kansanga."}}
```

which I'm getting from facebook when I query for nearby places, and I would like to extract the latitude, longitude, category and name.
This is what am trying

```
public void onCompleted(List<GraphPlace> places, Response response) {
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (CharSequence) places.listIterator(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ListIterator<GraphPlace> x =    places.listIterator();
    while(x.hasNext()){
        String f = x.next().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), f, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mytext.setText(f);
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(f);
            JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray( "GraphPlace" );
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), array.length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}   
});
request.executeAsync();
```

However, I can't seem to get an entry point, and however much I try, I can't get anything Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON string looks like this:

```
{"id":"268367713308665","category":"School","location":{"state":"","zip":"","longitude":32.631482614136,"latitude":0.24519375867929,"country":"Uganda","city":"Kampala","street":"PO BOX 28493"},"category_list":[{"id":"365182493518892","name":"School"}],"name":"Little Wonders Montessori"}}
```

To get latitude and longitude would be:

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourJSONVariableHere);
        JSONObject location = json.getJSONObject( "Location" );
        String lat = location.getString("latitude");
        String long = location.getString("longitude");
```

For the `lat` and `long` variables, you can assign `int` or `long` depending on the value of the JSON. If you change the variable type, you would do `getInt()` or `getLong` for the respective variable value.

The other things to keep in mind is that you have a nested object, which holds the `lat` and `long`, so you have to get that, then parse that. The same goes if you have nested arrays, or other objects. Currently you are using `getJSONArray`, but arrays in JSON have `[array, array]`, or square brackets, where JSON objects have `{object, object}` curly braces.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Blaine, so, i would like to know, if my string starts with GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphPlace, state= ...,i have to first format it and remove the first part that i don't want ??

Comment: I'm not really sure. I haven't seen a response like that. JSON doesn't use the `=` sign. Check the FB docs and see if there is a method associated with removing the needed code.